# Java EE Database Bottleneck - Cache

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, caching, jboss, infinispan

I'm writing an application that reads in a file via a gui, converts it to a different format, persists both files in a MySQL DB and presents the converted file as a download option to the user.

I was wondering what caching techniques / design patterns could be used to alleviate this potential bottle neck. For example, immediately cache both files post conversion (@CacheResult ?) and return cached file to user ASAP and only then persist the file to DB.

I am using JBoss and can use Infinispan for caching. I am guessing there must be established patterns for this type of use case I just don't know what they are!

Answer (score 0):

Your bottle neck is in the write, not the read.

Your OS will cache the files for you for reading. The only reason to cache is if you want more control over the lifespan of the cached file rather than relying on the inherent file system cache.

As for the writing, you could simply convert in to memory and then save it to the disk later, in the background. But you have no ACIDity doing it that way -- lose the system, you lose the conversion and the original data.

The real solution is to have decent I/O on the back end, such as a high end SAN/NAS appliance or simply a modern SSD.

Comment: Hi, 

thanks for the reply. I realise the write is the issue but i thought it would be much quicker to write to cache and return and write ti DB later, i.e. convert, cache and return. I agree that the loss of ACIDity is a problem for me thats why i was wondering if there was a simple pattern around this. For example a persistent cache with a long eviction time to handle h/w crash.

These are all just rambling thoughts in my head! Thanks for taking the time to reply...